# What is the definition of write across?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The headline is:

"Who Can Write About What?

Roxane Gay and Jay Caspian Kang debate writing across identity lines — and how to respond when an author gets it wrong."

'writing across identity lines". What would be to write across?

Answer (score 1):

The conversation which is linked discusses people of one 'identity' (e.g. Black, Asian, white, Mexican, American, British) writing about the lives, feelings, experiences, etc, of people of a different identity. There is imagined to be a 'line' dividing people of one identity from those of another, and writing about people of a different one is deemed to 'cross' those lines, thus is called 'writing across' by the article author. This can be done well, or badly. They discuss, among other things, White people writing about Black people's lives, and the British author Jim Grant ('Lee Child') who has written a series of novels about someone called Jack Reacher. One of the speakers thinks it is clear that he wrote the novels without having visited the United States beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

To do "writing across identity lines" would be for a member of one group to write from the point-of-view (PoV) of a member of a different group, or to write descibing what things are like for the other group.  For example, for a man to write from the PoV of a woman, particularly is a specifically female situation, such as a woman suffering the after -effects of rape, or undergoing childbirth. For another example, for a a European to write from teh PoV of a person from Africa, or for a very rich person to write from the PoV of a person in poverty.  Or perhaps fr a straight person to write from a gay PoV.

so the term used here isn't "write across" it is "across identity lines". The verB could also be "speak" or "act" .

M<any people believe that is is improper or problematic to write or speak on behalf of or in the place of a member of a different group. Others believe that such writing has a significant risk of badly misstating the views or responses of a member of a group that the writer is not a member of. That is the sort of thing being discussed in the quoted text.